# Why does NumberFormatter ignore my custom GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL?

Tags: php, number-formatting, numberformatter

***Code:***

```
$a = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
var_dump($a->formatCurrency(123456, 'USD'));

$a = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$a->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, '-');
var_dump($a->formatCurrency(123456, 'USD'));
```

***Actual output:***

```
string(11) "$123,456.00"
string(11) "$123,456.00"
```

***Expected output:***

```
string(11) "$123,456.00"
string(11) "$123-456.00"
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Just a note that it seems to work with `\NumberFormatter::DECIMAL`.

Comment: @NigelRen But it is not a normal number but a currency (money sum).

Comment: It was just an observation which means it is something to do with currencies and not something that doesn't work at all.

Comment: Seems like `formatCurrency` is designed to generally [ignore symbols](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.setsymbol.php#124153).